# second derivative test of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

A function is defined by $f(x, y) = \sin(mx)\cos(ny)$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Determine all of the extreme points and classify them as maximum, minimum or saddle point.

I have found $D$ to the extent where it  is:

$D= m^4n^4\sin^2(mx)\cos^2(ny)-m^2n^2\cos^2(mx)\sin^2(ny).$

How would I carry on with this question to finish it?

Answer (score 1):

Treat $x$ and $y$ as completely independent.

Extrema will exist where $\vec\nabla f(x,y) = 0$

which comes down to finding $x$ and $y$ given ...

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = m \cos(mx) \cos(ny) = 0   $$

and

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = -n \sin(mx) \sin(ny) = 0   $$

So $(x,y) = \left( \frac{2p+1}{2m}\pi ,\frac{q}{n}\pi \right)$ or $\left( \frac{p}{m}\pi ,\frac{2q+1}{2n}\pi \right)$ for all integers $p$ and $q$.